# .htaccess to control HTTPS on certain pages

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I am using htaccess to redirect certain pages to htaccess. The code am using is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /core/marketing/editprofile
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The page is redirecting for`/core/marketing/editprofile`, but it is not redirecting back to http for other pages after this.

Please tell me hos can i enable https to http redirection also?

Answer (score 0):

You must do the reverse for other pages:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /core/marketing/editprofile
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/marketing/editprofile
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```